# Clone Div with Diffrent button values

Tags: jquery

i have this div

```html
<div id="accordion" class="clone_div">
        <div class="card w-75">
            <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm text-right">
                                <span>הרשמה</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-sm">
                                <span>ש"ח 000</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </button>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" id="check_std" novalidate="novalidate">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm ">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" value="<?= $p_id ?>" name="p_id" placeholder="מספר ת.ז. *">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm ">
                                <input type="date" class="datepicker form-control" value="<?= $b_day ?>" name="b_day" placeholder="תאריך לידה*">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="search" value="search">
                    </form>

                    <div class="row mt-5 mr-1">
                        <form id="std_val" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" style="text-align: right">
                            <span class="mr-3">רישום <input type="radio" class="checkbox gn" name="gender" value="boy"> בן <input type="radio" name="gender" class="checkbox gn" value="girl"> בת </span>
                            <div class="row col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control  " value="<?= $row['std_name'] ?>"  placeholder="שם*">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="שם משפחה*">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2 ">
                                <div class="col-sm">

                                    <select class="form-control ">
                                        <option selected disabled>מוסד הלימודים*</option>
                                        <option value="אהלי תורה" >אהלי תורה </option>
                                        <option value="תלמוד תורה" >תלמוד תורה </option>
                                        <option value="בית רבקה צעירות" >בית רבקה צעירות </option>
                                        <option value="בית רבקה בוגרות" >בית רבקה בוגרות </option>
                                        <option value="גן" >גן </option>
                                        <option value="אחר" >אחר </option>

                                    </select>

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                        <option selected disabled>שם המורה/הגננת*</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2 ">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <select class="form-control ">
                                        <option selected disabled>מידת חולצה*</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                        <option selected disabled> מסיימת כיתה/גן*</option>
                                        <option value="גן ראשון">גן ראשון</option>
                                        <option value="גן תת חובה">גן תת חובה</option>
                                        <option value="גן חובה">גן חובה</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה א">כיתה א</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ב">כיתה ב</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ג">כיתה ג</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ג">כיתה ג</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ד">כיתה ד</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ה">כיתה ה</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ו">כיתה ו</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ז">כיתה ז</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ח">כיתה ח</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה ט">כיתה ט</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה י">כיתה י</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה יא">כיתה יא</option>
                                        <option value="כיתה יב">כיתה יב</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-7 mt-2 " style="width: 313px">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <select class="form-control  ">
                                        <option selected disabled> סוג קייטנה*</option>
                                        <option value="קייטנת ילדי הגנים" data-price = "280">קייטנת ילדי הגנים</option>
                                        <option value="קעמפ (מסיימות ה- ח)" data-price = "350">קעמפ (מסיימות ה- ח)</option>
                                        <option value="קעמפ (מסיימות א- ד)" data-price = "280">קעמפ (מסיימות א- ד)</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-7 mt-2 " style="width: 313px">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <select class="form-control  boy" style="display: none">
                                        <option selected disabled>  מידת כיפה*</option>

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-12 mt-lg-5 ">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value="health"> הצהרת בריאות
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="row col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                    <h4>פרטי האב</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control  " value="<?= $row['std_f_name'] ?>"  placeholder="שם האב*">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" placeholder="ת.ז. האב*">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">

                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control  " value=""  placeholder="מייל האב*">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " value="<?= $row['std_f_phone'] ?>" placeholder="נייד האב*">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-12 mt-3">
                                <div class="col-lg-12 mb-3">
                                    <h4>פרטי האם</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control  " value="<?= $row['std_m_name'] ?>"  placeholder="שם האב*">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " value="" placeholder="ת.ז. האם*">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row col-md-12 mt-2">
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control  " value=""  placeholder="מייל האם*">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control " value="<?= $row['std_m_phone'] ?>" placeholder="נייד האם*">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this div is a collapse. 
what I would like to do is when I clone it , the name of the button data-target will be data-target="#collapseOne1" and so on
and the div with the id of id="collapseOne" will gate the same value as the button data-target 
what i have tride so far is

```js
       $("#clone").click(function(){

            $('.clone_div')
                .clone()
                .attr('id', 'collapseOne'+ cloneCount++)
                .attr('data-target', '#collapseOne'+ cloneCount++)
                .attr('class', 'clone_div'+ cloneCount++)
                .appendTo(".result");

        });
```

but I don't get the proper result

Comment: "get the proper result" isn't helpful.  What do you get and also please provide all of the html and javascript.  There is no element with an id of clone nor do I see an element with a class of result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after.  You need to find each object in the clone that you want to change the attributes of.

```
    var cloneCount = 1

      $("#clone").click(function() {

                cloneCount++
        var clone = $('.clone_div')
          .clone();

                clone.attr('class', 'clone_div'+ cloneCount)
                clone.find("#collapseOne").attr("id","collapseOne" + cloneCount);
                clone.find("button").attr("data-target","#collapseOne" + cloneCount);
                clone.appendTo(".result");

  });
```